# How to Upgrade ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

How can I upgrade activeMQ version?

May I save kahdb, conf and lib folder from the old version and replace in the new version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on which versions are involved.

Generally:
* Install the new version, copy the Kahadb-files
* Copy conf folder
* Copy any custom libs, webapps, plugins etc that you installed manually
* Check all release notes for versions between "old" and "new". It will state any major changes you will need to account for. Examples: ObjectMessage security issues, Java 8 requirement, JDBC table changes, etc.

Regarding the conf, "activemq.xml", you should really go through the configuration and compare to the new version. Sometimes new features, configuration and default settings are introduced that you want to use in your custom config as well. If you are using config OOTB, this is easy, buy may be a bit harder with heavily modified activemq.xml configurations.

Comment: Thanks, Petter. I made a mistake when I migrate the version from 5.13.4 to 5.15.1, I just install a new version and replace the Kahadb from old to new version. ActiveMQ started and the queues were there. But 5 days later we realized that activeMQ was not writing in our database MYSQL and Messages appear to be stored in kahdb. I put the libs that were missing and I replace the activeMQ.xml from old to new version. Do you know how do I drain these messages?  Is it possible to 'transfer' them to MySQL?

Comment: sorry, configuration out of the box. Can't spell today :-)

Comment: There is some way to export the messages from Kahdb to my database? Some config in activemq.xml?